# circular UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Anyone knows how to make continuous values in a component of a custom picker, like months wheel in date `UIPickerView`? Here is my source array data:

```
self.one =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<=101; i++) {
    [one addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}

//and here my titleforrow method

if (component==0) {
    return [[one objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];
}
```

Comment: One possible solution would be to add objects to your array when the user scrolling is nearing the end of your data source.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DialController [here](http://dev.doukasd.com/2011/04/infinite-scrolling-dial-control-for-ios/).

There's a video and some example code.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this [`DLPickerView`](https://github.com/danleechina/DLPickerView). This picker view can totally replace `UIPickerView`. And yes, you can make `DLPickerView` scroll cyclically. And config many other new features that `UIPickerView` doesn't have.